# How to highlight region in google map by location name

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am new in google map i want to highlight region when user enter place name like "Delhi","Mumbai" and it should be highlight with red boundary.  google provides  same feature like this. I did google but i did not get any responsive answer.so can anyone tell me that how can i highlight region.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3 Highlight Country Border without using Polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964573/google-maps-api-v3-highlight-country-border-without-using-polygons)

Answer (score 1):

First you need the coordinates of the polygons of the regions that you want to highlight, then you can create for each of these new polygon that has the attributes stroke_ fill_ * and * that you need

Comment: so there are many cities how i will get coordinates for all cities. is there any way that generate dynamic coordinate whenever user enter place name