# KML file of a area in GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

I'm developing an application where I need the boundary of an area of google maps or earth in `KML` or `Shape` file. I need the co-ordinate of the polygon. How can I get this? Does any other platform like open street map has this kind of feature? I want co-ordinates like following

```xml
                <coordinates> -112.3348783983763,36.1514008468736,100
                  -112.3372535345629,36.14888517553886,100
                  -112.3356068927954,36.14781612679284,100
                  -112.3350034807972,36.14846469024177,100
                  -112.3358353861232,36.1489624162954,100
                  -112.3345888301373,36.15026229372507,100
                  -112.3337937856278,36.14978096026463,100
                  -112.3331798208424,36.1504472788618,100
                  -112.3348783983763,36.1514008468736,100 </coordinates>
```

[image]

Comment: Asking for offsite resources is off-topic for StackOverflow. gadm.org has kmz files of various administrative areas.  openstreetmap includes the data as well.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Google Maps API v3 Highlight Country Border without using Polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964573/google-maps-api-v3-highlight-country-border-without-using-polygons) and many others.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a feature request filed in Google's Public Issue Tracker for polygon generation in a specified geographic boundary. You can check it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816953

To express your interest, I suggest that you star the issue to get updates and leave comments for additional information.